# Make div responsive (transparent black box with text)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive

I am pretty much a CSS beginner and I need help to make a div I created responsive for mobile. Right now it doesn't resize and you can't read the text/see the whole box from mobile. I have this in the CSS editor:

```
.mod {
    position: relative;
    width: 875px;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.mod-text,
.mod-background {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15%;
    width: 100%;
}

.mod-text {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
}

.mod-background {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 8px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity: .6;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The reason I had it set to specific pixels is because I want the box to wrap around text and a snippet of code for a subscription form. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">` to the head of your document? And just a tip, don't use large fixed pixel sizes, use `em` or percentages instead. :)

Comment: I was able to set max-width to 75% but when I try to change the height to a percentage it just makes everything appear in a really thin line.

Comment: @ifvictr no I will try that. directly in the HTML of the page I'm editing or in the custom CSS pane?

Comment: I can't get that suggestion to work. Any time I change the height in the CSS, the box becomes a thin line.

Comment: It appears also that the text is not responsive. So I could use help with that too! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think the theme is pushing my content a little to the right on the homepage, but this is the CSS snippet that worked for me:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
  }
.content {
  position: relative;
  color: White;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
}
.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: Black;
  z-index: 1;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: .5;
}
.center {
     float: none;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
}
```